# Print Method in Assembly is printing random junk

Tags: assembly, nasm

The solution was to just add a `,0` to line 19, or `msg db "test", 0xa, 0xd`

## Question:

Im trying to print a string in assembly using a method i made, but when doing that, it prints random non-ascii char.

the file is as follows:

```
ORG 0x7C00

mov si, msg
call PrintStr
jmp $

PrintStr:
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, [si]
    psloop:
        mov al, [si]
        int 0x10
        inc si
        cmp al, 0
        jne psloop
        
ret

msg db "test", 0xa, 0xd

%include "./kernel.asm"
%include "./lib.asm"

times (510 - ($ - $$)) db 0x00
dw 0xAA55
```

the output is:

```
test
(some random non-ascii gibberish)
```

i use nasm if that helps

Comment: Add `,0` after `msg db "test", 0xa, 0xd`, and you should initialise `ds` to 0. The order also should be CR U+000D followed by LF U+000A.